# How to get DNS SERVER Statistics ? Total Queries per day ? (windows Server 2003)

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, active-directory, powershell

Using a script (powershell for example)
How can i get the total Queries on a DNS Server (Windows Server 2003 - Active Directory Environment) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try the [dnscmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756116%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_19) and it's statistics option. It's part of the resource kit.

Answer (score 0):

For now

-i use PERFMON with the DNS Counter: **Total Query Received/sec**

-Perform for 24hours

-output in CSV file

-Open with Excel and SUM all the value

Any other ways to script this step ?

Comment: There's a WMI DNS provider, but I don't know if it would give this anyways.  Does your perfmon approach work?  Using PowerShell to read in the CSVs and summing the values would be easy.  Answer the perfmon question and I can show how to sum once I test to see the format of the CSV.